# Is there a place where I can get all the popular and latest javascript library?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, shared-libraries

I use multiple javascript libraries, such as bootstrap, jquery, knockout and etc. Every time I start a new project, I have to add them manually to my layout page. It annoys me even its once per project. Nuget packager has been helpful for doing this. But as I use more libraries, nuget packager no longer fits my needs. So I'm looking for a better solution. My question is: Is there a place or visual studio plugin that can help me adding the popular and latest javascript libraries mentioned above?

Comment: You mean like [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use CDNs.  That way from one project to the next, I just need the same links in my html to get the same resources.  Here is a good resource.

[Javascripts CDN](http://cdnjs.com/)

Example code:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```